# Android MediaPlayer crashing app

Tags: android

I have an android app with a button that plays a sound. the code for playing the sound:

```
if (mp != null)
{
    mp.release();
}
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.match);
mp.start();
```

mp is a field in the activity:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
//variables:
MediaPlayer mp;
//...
```

The app runs ok, but after clicking the button about 200 times on the emulator, app crashed and gave me this error https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5488790/error.txt (couldn't figure how to post it here so it will appear decently) 
i am assuming this is because the MediaPlayer object is consuming up too much memory, but isn't mp.release() supposed to take care of this? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code should work, but obviously `release()` isn't really releasing everything.

Maybe it's because you have to reload `R.raw.match` every time you want to play the sound. If `R.raw.match` is just a short sound effect, then you might want to consider using `SoundPool` instead.

If you use `SoundPool` you only have to load `R.raw.match` once which may prevent the memory issues.

This tutorial has a good example on how to use it: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#tutorial_soundpool

You pretty much just make one instance of SoundPool then load the sound once and play it when you need it.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

If you want to use MediaPlayer...

```
public class Blah extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   MediaPlayer mp;

   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle b)
   {
      // blah blah
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(R.raw.match);

      // blah blah
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
      if (v.getId() == yourButtonID)
      {
         // play sound from beginning
         mp.seekTo(0);
         mp.start();
      }
   }
}
```

This way you only create one instance and whenever you want to play it, you just rewind it to the beginning then play.

Comment: thank you. it really is just a short sound effect. Is it good practice to use 2 SoundPool objects for 2 different effects i need to play? or should i use 1 SoundPool object and load it with the right sound effect before playing? If I understand correctly, my question should be - whats more expensive: loading a new resource into SoundPool each time you need to play a short sound effect, or just having 2 SoundPool objects each loaded with an effect I need to play?

Comment: You should just use 1 SoundPool object, then you can load both sounds in `onCreate` then just choose which sound to play when you want to play a sound.

Comment: To clarify, when you use `soundPool.load(whateverSound)` it returns an int index, which you should save as a variable to reference that sound when you want to play it later! and you're welcome! =]

Comment: i've followed the example almost exactly but put 2 ids of both of the raw sound effects that i have. it works, but the code of the example that's onCreate is giving me the same line on logcat over and over: E/AudioCache(   34): Heap size overflow! req size: 1052672, max size: 1048576
E/AudioCache(   34): Heap size overflow! req size: 1052672, max size: 1048576
E/AudioCache(   34): Heap size overflow! req size: 1052672, max size: 1048576

Comment: One of your files might be too big? I know a lot of people have this problem and there's no clear solution to it, since it's most likely a problem with the Android SDK itself.

Comment: yes, so i see here. a lot of people are asking exactly the same thing, no answer in sight. i see those warning lines on adb logcat, but it doesn't seem to affect the program. do you think it's ok to leave it this way? as for file sizes, one is 7.39KB, the other is 262KB. are these considered too big for SoundPool? Should i go back to MediaPlayer? (Please don't say that :) )

Comment: Whoops! not only this, after very little clicks the sound effects are not playing anymore and i get this in logcat (for each click): E/AudioFlinger(   34): no more track names available
E/AudioTrack(  822): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/SoundPool(  822): Error creating AudioTrack

Comment: The 262K one might be too big. For big files, it is recommended that you use MediaPlayer. For my game, I play the background music using MediaPlayer and the sound effects using SoundPool. Why is it recreating the track? You should only load it once and then you can play it multiple times.

Comment: i don't know. this is the code that's onClick, similar to the example: AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
   float actualVol = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   float maxVol = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   float vol = actualVol/maxVol;
   if (loaded)
   {
    soundpool.play(regularSound,vol,vol,1,0,1f);
   }

Comment: I know. it's because the tracks are recreating each time the activity starts onCreate. after a few times that's a problem. what do you suggest? Maybe i'll create them and put them into a static var, and then if it's null recreate it, else use the current one?

Comment: what do you mean? if you mean AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE); it is because it was on the example you showed me. it's supposed to make the hardware buttons control the app sound volume.

Comment: oh never mind. I misread your comment. You might want to use MediaPlayer to play your larger sound file. General rule of thumb is MediaPlayer for large sound files, SoundPool for small ones. I'm not sure how to get rid of the error except for trying that. I'm playing multiple sound files many times in my game and never ran into that problem. =/ Sorry.

Comment: sorry to pester you like this, but if i'll go back to playing the bigger file with MediaPlayer, wouldn't I come back to where i started with the app crashing because of a memory leak?

Comment: oh, I thought the answer you accepted solved your problem with MediaPlayer? I'll take a look at your problem again in a bit.

Comment: with this solution there will be a crash as well i assume, because the MediaPlayer instance is created again each time the activity starts. I guess i need to start it just once when the app starts, and then just use the same instance from elsewhere where ever i need it.

Comment: you assume or did you try it?

Comment: It's a matter of times that the object is created again and again. at first it was created onClick which makes the app crash pretty fast, but every 50 clicks also restart the activity once. so if the instance is created onCreate it would also crash eventually, but slower. I used a singleton to store the MediaPlayer instance, and i create it when app starts up for the first time. i will see if this causes the app to crash at any point and tell you. I really appreciate the time and your effort here, thanks again for helping out!

Answer (score 3):

If you are attaching a sound effect to a button, `MediaPlayer` in general is far too heavyweight for this operation.  You're getting unnecessary latency each time just to load up the sound data into memory.  You should look at using `SoundPool` instead.

In either case, there is no valid reason to release and re-create the `MediaPlayer` each time.  If you decide to use `MediaPlayer`, control the single instance you have with the button clicks.

```
MediaPlayer mp;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Other init code

    //Create the player this way so it doesn't auto-prepare
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.match);
    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    afd.close();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Release it only when no longer needed
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
    }
    //Play the sound
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
```

Hope that Helps, but again, I would highly recommend using `SoundPool` instead if this sound is just a short effect.

Comment: I agree he should probably be using SoundPool. But curious, why wouldn't you call mp.prepare() from onCreate(), then mp.seekTo(0); mp.start(); in onButtonClick()?

Comment: @newbyca What if this activity you wrote here gets recreated 50 times? wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @user1555863 did you mean to ask Devunwired? ... Regardless, no, launching this activity 50 times shouldn't be a problem. Instead of taking my word for it though, you should hook up a unit test to this activity and try it out yourself. You can test 50 iterations, you can test 1000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (mp != null)
        {
            mp.release();
        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.match);
        mp.prepare(); // not needed 
        mp.start();
```

Good luck!!

Comment: MediaPlayer.create() takes care of prepare. No need for it there

Comment: Also the docs say that `prepare()` must not be called after `create(...)`.

Comment: @mario so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

if you hold the MediaPlayer, release it at the end of the activity

```
@Override
void onDestroy() {

    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.